# Before and after callback

Tags: jquery

I use the great [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin. I need to be able to execute something BEFORE and AFTER the execution of the sort click

How do you ADD a before and after callback method to a plugin that dont have it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Couldn't you use the sortStart and sortEnd [triggers](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-triggers.html)?

Comment: Seems to be the intended purpose.

Comment: here is the working code with your proposed solution : $("#myTable").bind("sortStart",function() { $("tr:odd").removeClass("odd"); }).bind("sortEnd",function() { $("tr:odd").addClass("odd"); });

Comment: if you have users who like their rows numbered... `}).bind("sortEnd",function() { $(this).find("tr").each(function(i){ if(i>0)$(this).find("td").first().html(i); }) });`  after sort renumber the # column, loop through all rows and for every row except the first (header), in the first <td> output as text the row counter

Answer (score 1):

I just got an answer from the author :

```
Hi!

There is an option for zebra stripes.

Example:
$("#tablesorter-demo").tablesorter({widgets: ['zebra']});

Best regards
Christian
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have it, you'll have to dig into the code and add it yourself. If the project has an open repository, consider submitting your contribution.

Comment: is it possible to capture the click event and to it here ?

Answer (score 0):

Add code to $headers.click(function(e) { .... } inside tablesorter.js file.